# Format for setting command line arguments when debugging in Visual C++

Tags: command-line-arguments, visual-c++-2010

I can see this has more or less been answered but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm debugging a console application using Visual C++ 2010. It requires some input arguments so through `Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments` I set these arguments. However, for some reason if the input in the box is `"-r 700 -i data\military.pri -v on"` then argc = 2 and they get parsed incorrectly.

Could it be that I'm formating it wrong? Do I need ", ', or comma's anywhere?

Or is it impossible that the format is wrong and is the problem somewhere else? It works when running it through the command prompt with the same arguments.

Comment: Alright, once again I found my own answer (I should really start waiting with asking questions :P). 

The proper format is JUST the input string, just like you would put it in the command line, no ,;'" or anything else, just spaces between the arguments.

The problem was that I was trying to make it read the file "data\military.pri", but that is the path to it from the Release.exe, not the Debug.exe :). (Posting it here because I can't answer my own question yet)

Comment: I had the exact same question, good find +1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the build configuration (DEBUG/RELEASE/whatever others you've created) for which you are entering the command line arguments matches what you are actually running.  If you set the command line arguments up for the DEBUG build and then you run in RELEASE mode, you won't get the proper arguments.

Could this be your problem?

Comment: Sadly, no, I checked-double-checked-triple-checked that :).